# How to run a bash script that installs rpms from a current rpm spec file?

Tags: linux, bash, rpm, yum, rpmbuild

I have this internal software installer that has a size > 4.9GBs, 
it installs a bunch of rpms/libraries and set some configs at the end.
I need to create a RPM using rpmbuild(Im new to this rpm creation) in order to install the RPM and also proceed to install/execute this installer(its a bash file).

My rpm spec is currently doing this at (you can check the code below):

%install

- Copy 2 zips files into a specific folder.
  This are 2 zip files from the actual software folder, I just splitted its
  content in 2 parts and zip them to avoid the max size limitations(4gbs if Im 
  not wrong).

%post

- Unzip those files into a specific folder.
- run the bash script installer that was inside those zip files (it will run silently because a -s flag that it has).
- Complete the bash and rpm installation successfully.

I had alredy built the rpm, so when I try to:

yum install .rpm,

it does the zip part just fine but it stays forever doing nothing at the bash installation part, maybe because this rpm lock thing, but I'm not sure.

By the way, Im not sure at all if this is a good approach for this at the end, I mean combined this rpm and installation stuff

So because the install.sh part is giving me this issues I tried this different changes:

sudo /root/sotfware/install.sh -silent /root/software/silent_configfile.conf

/root/sotfware/install.sh -silent /root/software/silent_configfile.conf

./root/sotfware/install.sh -silent /root/software/silent_configfile.conf

What do you guys thisnk I'm doing wrong?,
Whats the best way to do this? or
Whats you recommendation for this?

This is the spec file:

```
Name:        software-19
Version:     1.0
Release:     1
Summary:     software 2019
License:     N/A
URL:         https://
AutoReqProv: no
AutoReq:     no

%description
Some description

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/root/software2019

cp /root/software/software-1.zip %{buildroot}/root/software2019/software-1.zip
cp /root/software/software-2.zip %{buildroot}/root/software2019/software-2.zip

%post
unzip /root/software/software-1.zip -d /root/software2019/
unzip /root/software/software-2.zip -d /root/software2019/rpm/
sudo /root/software/install.sh -s /root/software2019/silent_configfile.conf
rm -rf /root/software/

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files
/root/software/*

%changelog
* Tue Jan 20 2019 1.0
  - Initial release
```

Hopefully Im been clear, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to learn more about packaging, then go to https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues here

1. You are building RPMs as `root`, which is dangerous and can wipe your machine if you don't write things correctly. Since you're just getting started, this is much more likely.
2. The source files shouldn't have absolute paths.
3. You shouldn't use `sudo` because RPM installation is always run as `root`.
4. `silent_configfile.conf` wasn't included in the RPM, so the target machine might not have it.
5. The `%post` deletes the files that you told RPM you would install, likely causing errors.

   1. This would also break `rpm -V` verification.
6. You are misusing the RPM system by doing a third-party install in your `%post`.

   1. This breaks things like `rpm -q --whatprovides /root/software19/myfile`.
   2. This breaks `rpm -V` because it cannot verify the files you installed.
   3. This breaks any concept of uninstall / upgrade because you don't provide `%preun` and related files to "do the right thing."

To do things right and not cause your admins headaches for years to come, you need to have those installers run during RPM creation (again, *not* as `root`!) with a target of `%{buildroot}` and then distributing the resulting file structure as an RPM. If this is not something that can be done, then RPM is probably not going to work for you and you need to look at other distribution options, like custom scripts.